# Ruby Regex error

Tags: ruby, regex, syntax-error

My regex:

```
https?://[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+(?:/[\w-]+)*(?:[./%?=&#-]\w+)+)?
```

In Ruby, I get the following error:

```
unmatched close parenthesis:/https?://[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+(?:/[\w-]+)*(?:[./%?=&#-]\w+)+)?/'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You'll probably want to escape those forward slashes, too.

Comment: Poor Shah got voted down, but sometimes asking the obvious question helps others out. Helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how I could be clearer than the error message.  Your regex has an unmatched close parenthesis.

```
https?://[\w-]+(?:.[\w-]+)+(?:/[\w-]+)*(?:[./%?=&#-]\w+)+)?
```

Notice how there's 3 `(` and 4 `)`

Further reading in regexes http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Specifically, you may want to check out the character information http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be one "close parenthesis" too much.
as it also says in the error message ;)